# Windows 10 Mail program never syncs automatically

Tags: windows-10, windows-mail

I installed Windows 10 late Tuesday night and I've configured several e-mail accounts in Mail. Three of them are Microsoft Outlook accounts and two are Gmail accounts. For each account I've set Mail to:

(a) Fetch new messages as they arrive

(b) Download messages from all time

There is no other special setting.

However, Mail never seems to fetch anything automatically as they arrive. In fact, I always receive my e-mail on my phone long before they show up in my inbox. As a test, for most of yesterday and today I waited about an hour after messages arrived in my phone, and each time I found that until I had manually synced the account, the messages did not appear in Mail.

I am certain that my Internet connection is working, because I get Skype messages in real time.  I am sure my computer has the correct drivers, because not only did I install everything from the manufacturer's site, I even ensured that there were no errors in Device Manager.  My computer has plenty of RAM and CPU horsepower. There is no reason for Mail not to sync except if it has a bug.

Does anyone have either a solution or a workaround?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I updated the Mail app today and it seems to be fixed now

Comment: @VarunAgw How did you update the Mail app?  When I run the updater, I only get the latest signatures for Windows Defender, not an update for Mail.

Comment: Open `Store` app and choose `Download and updates`. After updating the mail app, it is now showing version as `17.6121.42001.0` in About section