# Windows 10 Mail app does not sync messages automatically

Tags: email, windows-10, sync, windows-mail

I've upgraded my HP Envy Ultrabook with preinstalled Windows 8 to Windows 10 about a month ago. All works enough smoothly - except the intrinsic Windows Mail & Calendar apps. They don't sync their contents automatically, even with my main Microsoft account linked to my Outlook.com email!

I tried different mailbox sync settings ("as items arrive", "every 15 minutes", etc.) - nothing helps. I tried to disconnect my local account from Microsoft account, and even created a new user from scratch - no result again.

The auto-sync also does not work for other mail accounts, not only for Outlook.com. Sometimes I even get the following error when trying to sync manually:

[image: Windows 10 Mail app sync error 0x86000c0a]

It seems, the problem is in a system service that should sync all personal data from my Microsoft account automatically. When I open the Mail app, I see the informational message like "Last updated 8 days ago" at the bottom of the message list. When I click the Sync this view toolbox button, the app downloads the fresh contents without problems in the vast majority of cases.

If somebody knows a concrete recipe that may help, write it, please. Don't send me to the following source, it did not help:

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Resolve-Sync-issues-in-Mail-and-Calendar-apps-in-Windows-10-0dd86c69-18f3-4f73-9d3d-375bdc9c3e34

The solution with updating the Mail app described here also does not work as I the Store app tells me the Mail app is installed and I have the latest version:

[Windows 10 Mail program never syncs automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/948622/windows-10-mail-program-never-syncs-automatically)

Perhaps, I need to reinstall the app using a PowerShell command or something like that - I do not know...

Comment: You should supply us with the version of the Mail application you are using currently.

Comment: @Ramhound, it's 17.6306.42251.0

Comment: You can reach hotmail.com within a browser.  Update your question with any new information you want to provide.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sure I can use Outlook.com in all 3 browsers I have and also on my Windows Phone phones ;)

Comment: @Ramhound, I also removed the app using the `Get-AppxPackage *windowscommunicationsapps* | Remove-AppxPackage` command in PowerShell and reinstalled it again, but this did not help.

Comment: **Update your question;**  I didn't ask if you could reach outlook.com i asked if you could reach hotmail.com.   The error indicates you cannot which tells me you likely have a DNS problem.  I realize hotmail was renamed outlook but the two domain are not identical.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sorry, it was not clear what you meant. When I type in "hotmail.com" in the address bar and press ENTER, I'm redirected to outlook.com to my mailbox (https://dub129.mail.live.com/default.aspx).

Comment: @Ramhound, Is there an activity log of the Mail app I can view?